# Combinatorial Laplacian for homology with $Z_2$ coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory

Consider I have boundary operators $\partial_1$,  $\partial_2$:
$\partial_1 \circ \partial_2 = 0$. Then if interested in $\text{ker}\,\partial_1 / \text{im}\,\partial_2$ one can study $\text{ker}\,(\partial_1^T\partial_1 + \partial_2\partial_2^T)$. However this is only true if I can define non-degenerate inner product in order to relate $(\text{im})^{\perp}$ and $\text{ker}$.
But can I some how generalise this if I have $Z_2$ coefficients?